# how to extract missing data-points in python data-frame

Tags: python, dataframe, missing-data

I want to find the missing data points in the python data frame. Below is a sample of the data frame.

[image]

For this example, 2020-06-19 11:48:35 data point is missing. So I want to find all the missing data points(missing seconds). How to find this dataframe's missing datapoints.(Normal interval between datapoints is one second. if any second is missing,want to put them to new dataframe).

What I tried:
I tried to plot it using a line chart .but its really hard to find missing datapoints in that chart. maybe creating a new dataframe with missing data points will be a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and [df.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
date_range = pd.date_range(df.time.min(), df.time.max(), freq='s')

df2 = df.set_index('time').reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'time'})
print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
                 time  WindSpeed
0 2020-06-19 11:48:32       3.11
1 2020-06-19 11:48:33       3.37
2 2020-06-19 11:48:34       4.28
3 2020-06-19 11:48:35       0.00
4 2020-06-19 11:48:36       5.34
5 2020-06-19 11:48:37       5.87
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Generating sequence of timestamps, since start-date, with one second inteval
times = [((datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 9, 10, 0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1) * x).time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for x in range(5)]

# Creating new data-frame with [ 'time', 'WindSpeed' ] columns, for each timestamp in sequence
missing_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'time' : times, 'WindSpeed' : [0] * len(times)})

# Filtering out timestamps existing in original dataframe using the `isin` function
missing_df = missing_df[~original_df.time.isin(times)]
```